# Why can't I get a value of Current When I implemented IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I did below work

```
class Program
{
    class GenEnumerator<T> : IEnumerable
    {
        public T[] Values { get; set; }


        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Values.Length; i++)
                yield return Values[i];
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GenEnumerator<string> g = new GenEnumerator<string>();
        g.Values = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
        g.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();

        Console.WriteLine(g.GetEnumerator().Current);


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

`g.GetEnumerator().Current` is always null.

but if I do this - `var a = g.GetEnumerator();`

the Current proeperty gets a value and works fine

Does it imply that I have to explicitly inherit the class from `IEnumerator` and implement its methods and property if I want to use `Current` without a `IEnumerator` type variable?

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: `GetEnumerator()` always returns a *new* enumerator. It's possible for *multiple* enumerators to be used simultaneously. They don't all share a single position.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because in order for the `Current` to become non-null, you need to call `MoveNext()` on the same object.

Your current code calls `MoveNext()` on a temporary object. Here is what's going on when you call

```
g.GetEnumerator().MoveNext()`;
Console.WriteLine(g.GetEnumerator().Current);
```

- A call of `GetEnumerator()` returns an object `x`
- A call `x.MoveNext()` is performed
- `x` becomes eligible for garbage collection, because it is not referenced from any variable in your program.
- When you call `g.GetEnumerator().Current`, a new object `y` is returned
- A call to `y.Current` is made, returning `null`, because there was no call of `MoveNext` on object `y`

When you add a variable `a`, however, you call `MoveNext` and `Current` on the same object, fixing the problem:

- A call of `GetEnumerator()` returns an object `x`, which is assigned to variable `a`
- A call `a.MoveNext()` is performed
- A call `a.Current` is performed

Answer (score 11):

You're creating new instances of `GenEnumerator` everytime by calling `GetEnumerator`, that's why your `Current` is `null`. Instead store it in a field and use that.

```
var e = g.GetEnumerator();
if(e.MoveNext())
{
    var current = e.Current;
}
```